# rails after_save infinite loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model which stores the details for retail outlets.

In Outlet model I have a before filter

```
after_save :is_outlet_verified

def is_outlet_verified
    if self.latitude.present? && self.longitude.present?
      self.update_attributes(:is_verified => true)
    else
      self.update_attributes(:is_verified => false)
    end
  end
```

I want to set `is_verified` field to `true` if outlet is geocoded. However when is_outlet_verified is successfully executed, it triggers after_save callback which again triggers is_outlet_verified.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ideally you would do something like this in a `before_save` callback, not `after_save` - just set the `is_verified` attribute and then just let the save take place as normal.

If you really need to do this, you can use `update_column` instead of `update_attribute`, which will skip all callbacks.

One caveat to note - if a `before_save` callback returns false, then the save will not go ahead.

Comment: you have a small typo in you method name `update_columns` as http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_columns

Answer (score 5):

`.update_attributes` invokes the `.save` method, so calling it `after_save` creates an infinite loop

I'd do it `before_save`, like this:

```
before_save :is_outlet_verified

  def is_outlet_verified
    if self.latitude.present? && self.longitude.present?
      self.is_verified = true
    else
      self.is_verified = false
    end
  end
```

Comment: No, but in update sql query, it doesn't update the is_verified field.

Comment: here's the query 'UPDATE "outlets" SET "latitude" = 12.0, "longitude" = 72.0, "updated_at" = '2014-03-05 11:40:03.777557' WHERE "outlets"."id" = 26'

Comment: Hmmmm it should update the is_verified option. Can you not see any issues in the logs?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `after_create` instead of `after_save` to avoid infinte loop occurred by `update_attributes`

Comment: But I want to execute that method everytime I make any changes to the given record.

Comment: then use `after_commit` https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/da840d13da865331297d5287391231b1ed39721b

Answer (score 2):

I recently I faced this issue and I solved to use this :)

**update_columns**(attributes) public

Updates the attributes directly in the database issuing an `UPDATE SQL` statement and sets them in the receiver:

```
user.update_columns(last_request_at: Time.current)
```

This is the fastest way to update attributes because it goes straight to the database but take into account that in consequence the regular update procedures are totally bypassed. In particular:

`Validations` are **skipped**.

`Callbacks` are **skipped**.

`updated_at/updated_on` are **not updated**.

This method raises `an +ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError+` when called on new objects, or when at least one of the attributes is marked as readonly.